Is the analytical fourier transform of an exponential decay the same as the FFT of a time series of the same signal?
Analytical Fourier Transform of $e^{-t/2}$:

FFT of a time series representation of $e^{-t/2}$:

I'm trying to find the decay coefficiencts in tri-eponential decay signals, and as a logical starting place, I thought I should look at the fourier transform of some exponential decays.
At first I got quite excited as the fourier transform of the analytical solution, 3
$$F[A_1e^{-t/\tau_1}](\omega) = \frac{A_1}{i\omega+1/\tau_1},$$
produces a peak at $1/\tau_1$ which is the answer that I'm looking for, especially as the fourier transform is a linear operation so the triexponential decay would work just as well for this and allow me to identify the coefficients of all three decays with one method.
The issue is that when I apply an FFT to a time signal representation of the same signal, an entirely different frequency distribution is produced as you can see in the image above. I have tried augmenting the signal by mirroring it about the y axis, and changing it to $Heaviside(t) * e^{-t/2}$ but neither of these changes has modified the FFT in a way that makes it more analysable.
Have I made a mistake somewhere or are fourier transforms fundamentally unlike discrete transforms of the same signal?
Code included for completeness:
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.fft import fft, fftfreq

def plot_ft(signal_fft, re_lim=2.0, im_lim=2.0):
    w_real = np.linspace(-re_lim, re_lim, 500)
    w_imag = np.linspace(-im_lim, im_lim, 500)
    W_real, W_imag = np.meshgrid(w_real, w_imag)
    W = W_real + 1j * W_imag
    Z = signal_fft(W)

    # Create a grid of subplots
    plt.figure(figsize=(18, 6))
    # Plot the real part
    plt.subplot(131)
    plt.pcolormesh(w_real, w_imag, Z.real, cmap='viridis')
    plt.xlabel('Re')
    plt.ylabel('Im')
    plt.colorbar()
    plt.title('Real Part of the FT')

    # Plot the imaginary part
    plt.subplot(132)
    plt.pcolormesh(w_real, w_imag, Z.imag, cmap='viridis')
    plt.xlabel('Re')
    plt.ylabel('Im')
    plt.colorbar()
    plt.title('Imaginary Part of the FT')

    # Plot the absolute values
    plt.subplot(133)
    plt.pcolormesh(w_real, w_imag, np.abs(Z), cmap='hsv', norm='log')
    plt.xlabel('Re')
    plt.ylabel('Im')
    plt.colorbar()
    plt.title('Absoulte values of the FT')

    # Display the plots
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()

# Generate a time series representation of an exponential function
def generate_timeseries(datapoints, tau=1.0, signal_type='standard'):
    t = np.linspace(0, 100, datapoints)
    if signal_type == 'standard':
        V = np.exp(-t/tau)
    else:
        t_before = np.linspace(-100, 0, datapoints)[:-1]
        if signal_type == 'mirror':
            V = np.append(np.exp(t_before/tau), np.exp(-t/tau))
        elif signal_type == 'heaviside':
            V = np.append(np.zeros_like(t_before), np.exp(-t/tau))
        else:
            raise ValueError("Error: signal_type must be one of 'standard', 'mirror', 'heaviside'")
        t = np.append(t_before, t)
    return t, V

# Perform a discrete fourier transform on t and V and sort for interpolation
def ft(t, V):
    Vf = fft(V)
    tf = fftfreq(len(t), t[1] - t[0])

    # Sort the frequency components for interpolation
    sorted_indices = np.argsort(tf)
    tf = tf[sorted_indices]
    Vf = Vf[sorted_indices]
    return tf, Vf

# Define a function to interpolate the FFT result
def create_signal_fft(tf, Vf):
    def signal_fft(w):
        real_interp = np.interp(w.real, tf, Vf.real)
        imag_interp = np.interp(w.imag, tf, Vf.imag)
        return real_interp + 1j * imag_interp
    return signal_fft


# Plot the analytical Fourier transform
def analytical_ft(w, tau=0.5):
    return 1 / (1j * w + 1/tau)

plot_ft(analytical_ft, re_lim=5.0, im_lim=5.0)

# Now the time_series version
t, V = generate_timeseries(10000, tau=0.5, signal_type='standard')

tf, Vf = ft(t, V)
signal_fft = create_signal_fft(tf, Vf)
plot_ft(signal_fft, re_lim=20.0, im_lim=20.0)


Sorry, but plotting this as a meshgrid makes no sense to me. In either case the transfer functions are a single function of a single variable. There is nothing 3D about it, so a simple plt.plot(freqAxis, abs(Vf) should do it. The axes labelling also seems nonsensical. But no: the FFT is not the same. An exponential decay is NOT bandlimited and hence it cannot be sampled without some amount of aliasing. There will always be some amount of error. The extent will depend on sample rate and FFT length.

@Hilmar Yes it's a single variable, but isn't it complex? Is there any reason why the frequency can't be complex? My idea was to plot essentially an argand diagram where the colour at each point would represent the frequency at that point thus allowing me to identify relevant peaks and their locations. Regardless of this though, The exponential decay not being band-limited makes perfect sense, and I agree with your comments about aliasing, however, as far as I can tell, the discreet one doesn't seem to tend to the Analytical one no matter how many points I add. There's no tau peak.

Ah, I understand now. Yes, frequency can be complex but that means but that means you have the Laplace plane in the continuous domain and the Z-plane in the discrete domain. These have completely different geometries and that's exactly what you are seeing. The concept of normal frequency maps to the imaginary axis in the Laplace Transform and to the unit  circle in the Z transform

The main problem here is that you want to evaluate the transfer functions over a complex plane. For continuous systems that's typically done using the Laplace Transform and for discrete systems you use the Z transform. The transform variables relate to the ordinary frequency $\omega$ in geometrically very different ways.
For the Laplace Transform that's simply the imaginary axis
$$ s = j \omega $$
For the Z transform it's the unit circle andit depends on the sample rate, i.e.
$$ z = e^{j \omega/f_s} $$
where $f_s$ is the sample rate. You can map both geometries into each other through the bilinear transform but it's probably easiest to just evaluate both at the same ordinary frequency.
Below is an example of how that would look like.
So you get similar results but there are discrepancies specifically at high frequencies. That's because the exponential decay is not bandlimited and you end up with aliasing. There are various different ways to interpret the discrepancy (periodic repetition, real phase at Nyquist, bilinear distortion of the frequency axis, etc) but is certainly there.

Here is the code
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.fft as fft

# %% Continous and discrete version of 1 kHz lowpass filter sampled at 48 kHz
fs = 48000   # sample rate
fc = 1000    # cutoff frequency
nx = 16384   # number of points

tau = 1 / 2 / np.pi / fc   # time constant in seconds
t = np.arange(0, nx) / fs  # time axis
h0 = np.exp(-t / tau)      # impulse responses
h0 = h0 / np.sum(h0)       # normailze to 0 dB
freqAxis = np.arange(0, nx // 2 + 1) / nx * fs

# calculate the continous version normalized to 0dB
fCont = 1.0 / (2j * np.pi * freqAxis * tau + 1)
fDiscrete = fft.rfft(h0)   # FFT

# %% and plot it
plt.clf()
plt.semilogx(freqAxis, 20 * np.log10(abs(fCont)), label='Continous')
plt.semilogx(freqAxis, 20 * np.log10(abs(fDiscrete)), label='Discrete')
plt.legend()
plt.grid(True)
plt.xlabel('Frequency in Hz')
plt.ylabel('Level in dB')
plt.xlim((10, fs / 2))


Okay, so would I be correct in saying that you can then take a series of points on the unit circle of the z domain up to the nyquist frequency and then essentailly map these points over to where they would be on the s domain and you would then have an accurate estimation of the s domain (in the area that we care about for this application) for low frequency points?
I'm still trying to teach myself about signal processing and this has been a bit of a trial by fire.
